# R: rgl package's writePLY function not writing Vertex Colors correctly

Tags: r, blender, mesh, rgl, parametric-equations

This is a fun exercise which uses the *rgl* package to draw a 3D parametric apple, and write the resulting mesh to a file.  The object shows the colors correctly in the "RGL Device" window (see screenshot below).  However, when I try opening the resulting .PLY file using Blender, the colors do not show correctly (meshlab doesn't work either).

**Question: How do I fix the code so that the apple's colors are imported correctly to blender.**

This example below produces the apple object on the screen, and a ".ply"

```
require(rgl)
require(plot3D)

M  <- mesh(seq(-pi, pi, length.out = 200),
           seq(-0.8*pi, pi, length.out = 170))
u  <- M$x
v  <- M$y
R1 <- 4
R2 <- 4
# Apple parametric Equation from http://www.econym.demon.co.uk/isotut/real.htm
x <- cos(u)*(R1 + R2*cos(v)) + ((v/pi)^100)
y <- sin(u)*(R1 + R2*cos(v)) + 0.25*cos(5*u)
z <- - 2.3*log(1 - v*0.3157) + 6*sin(v) +2*cos(v)
zlim <- range(z)
zlen <- zlim[2] - zlim[1] + 1
colorlut <- rainbow(zlen)
col <- colorlut[ z - zlim[1] + 1 ]
surface3d(x, y, z, col=col, smooth=TRUE)
writePLY('apple_v07.ply',
         pointRadius = 0.005, pointShape = icosahedron3d(),
         withColors=TRUE)
```

[image: 3D apple produced parametrically, however, mesh file is not created with the colors correctly]

Comment: I tried to find an example of a .ply file with colour that I could import into Blender, but I couldn't find one.  Do you know an example that works?  Then we could compare what it does to what `rgl` does.

Comment: I've found an example now (in a comment to http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36783/import-ply-doesnt-display-vertex-colors).  I don't get the full range of colours when viewing the apple, but if I shrink it I do (by shrinking the 200 by 170 mesh to just 20 by 17):  so I suspect the problem is with the import, not the exported file.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the problem is in the file produced by `rgl`, and not in the code that imports it?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that writePLY mistakenly declares vertex colors as floating point when in fact it outputs uchar (unsigned byte integer).

Output to ASCII and change the four color definitions (including alpha) to uchar and problem solved.
See image link below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/527BO.png)

Comment: Can you provide the code to your proposed solution?

Comment: Well this is a manual edit, I haven't modified the writePLY function yet (which would be the solution), but here is an example:

Original output:
ply
format ascii 1.0
element vertex 1196667 
property float x
property float y
property float z
property float red
property float green
property float blue
property float alpha
property float nx
property float ny
property float nz
element face 398889 
property list int int vertex_indices
end_header

Corrected output:
ply
...
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
property uchar alpha

Comment: Apologies for the above, comments can't be formatted with newlines aparently.